# .zsh appearance faulty in apple terminal but not in iterm2

Tags: terminal, zsh, iterm2

For the last year, I've been using iTerm2 instead of the built-in terminal for my Macbook. I just started using VSCode and noticed that my terminal is really hard to read because it's not properly viewing fonts, colors, and characters. [Here is how my apple terminal looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYP12.png). How can make my apple terminal look coherent and pretty without messing up how my iTerm2 shell looks like? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the escape codes for controlling colours (and maybe cursor  movement) are not recognized. Compare the values of the environment variables `TERM` (i.e. `echo $TERM`) and `PS1`, and also - for the safe side - `LANG` and `LC_ALL` between the "good" and the "bad" terminal. Also compare the value of the variables `ZSH_VERSION` and `-` (i.e. `echo $-`) in both cases, and run a `setopt` in both terminals and compare the output.

Comment: For the **really** safe side (I have been bitten by this type of errors too often), verify that you really run Zsh in both terminals. The easiest way to do this is to enter a line with a single closing parenthesis, `)`.